# Fastest way to display result of count(*) with mySQL (Preferably in one line)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There are multiple moments where I want to simply show a scalar coming back from a count(*) request but I feel like there's a one-liner I could use to replace that. 
Here is what I am doing :

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY='X'");
$line=$result->fetch_assoc();
echo $line["COUNT(*)"];
```

isn't there a way I could simply do something like

```
echo $result["COUNT(*)"]->fetch_assoc()->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY='X'");
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: better is rename function like a COUNT(*) AS product_count

Comment: You are doing the chaining backward, also a little easier with `->fetch_object()` and a column alias - `echo $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY='X'")->fetch_object()->count;`. You need to do the query, then fetch, then the column.

Comment: A single line of code chaining everything together isn't necessarily faster, it's fewer characters to type, and probably harder to read.... speed isn't everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this, you need to fix your chaining.
This

```
echo $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM devtools_log")->fetch_assoc()["COUNT(*)"];
```

should work.

EDIT: Didn't see Sean's comment. It is a bit more extensive :)